# Specify a Healthcheck for a load balancer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, health-monitoring

I have a web application (a jupyter notebook server) that lives inside a docker container on AWS because it does not have endpoint made specifically for healthcheck, the load balancer cannot check that that it is working properly and my ecs container fails regularly with the message: 
`Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbal`. My questions is is it possible to parametrize the healthcheck of the load balancer so it checks if the login page responds and consider the healthcheck succesful if it is the case. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to create an endpoint in your application something like `/health` and return HTTP status code `200`. LB health check does not read or look into the body it just checks the response **http status code** if you are using application LB.

LB will just ping the login path, but the issue come when `/login` does not return status code `200` and of course it will not return `200` as the login will not consider successful without the body.

Do ssh and  `curl -I yourendpoint:port/login` and check the http respoonse code suppose its 401.

Then goto target group -> health check -> edit

The update status code accordingly
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to parametrize the healthcheck of the load balancer so
>   it checks if the login page responds and consider the healthcheck
>   succesful if it is the case

Yes, you would set the [HealthCheckPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html) parameter to whatever the login page path is.